# Django best practice for displaying mostly read-only form, one field writeable

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement where one user creates an 'instance' of an object via a ModelForm. Another user of a different group has access to read all of the fields of the form, but has to update only one field. Think of a student who creates an exam object. Then a teach pulls up the exam and just needs to put in a grade, the rest of the exam is read only.

What's the best way to do that? Should I just query for the object, and display each field individually, then create a form (not a ModelForm?) for just the one field?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I just query for the object, and display each field individually, then create a form (not a ModelForm?) for just the one field?

This is probably the best way to go about it. Note you **can** use a `ModelForm` for the teacher form, see the Django documentation on [using a subset of fields on a model form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form). You will have to display all the other fields manually in your template, but you should probably have a separate template for this view (I would use separate views as well).

You could find some code for a read only field on [Django Snippets](http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/readonly/), but generally it's better to be explicit about what fields you are updating from each view. This is likely to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: +1: ModelForm with a subset of fields is best, list this option first.  The special-purpose non-model form is a larger pain and not as obvious a solution.  It's easy to have multiple model forms for different classes of users or different use cases.

Comment: using a subset of the fields will result in the form not displaying the rest of the fields - not optimal if you want them to be able to see the data entered, but not edit it. You can always apply a disabled = True attribute to the widget for each of the form fields. See the docs - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: S.Lott: Good idea, revised my answer slightly.
Rishabh: Yes, displaying the fields not in the form was covered in the text I quoted. I have made it more explicit in my revision.